# $(C (X,Y),d)$ is complete

Tags: metric-spaces, compactness, complete-spaces

I am interested in a proof of the following statement:

> Let $(X,d_X)$ be a compact metric space and $(Y,d_Y)$ be a complete space. Then for $f,g\in C (X,Y)$ the metric $$d(f,g):=\sup_{x\in X}d_Y(f(x),g(x))$$ turns $(C(X,Y),d)$ into a complete metric space.

However, I can't find this statement in any of my (beginner's) books and also searching on the internet hasn't turned up anything. I would be thankful if someone could provide a script or notes where I could read it. Unfortunately, my mathematical abilites are far from trying to prove it on my own (I would be happy to just be able to understand it) and I hope that asking for a complete proof on this page isn't inappropriate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $(f_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ be a Cauchy sequence of elements of your space. I will prove that it converges.

Let $x\in X$. For each $\varepsilon>0$, there is a natural $p$ such that$$m,n\geqslant p\implies d_Y\bigl(f_m(x),f_n((x)\bigr)\leqslant d(f_m,f_n)<\varepsilon.$$Therefore, $\bigl(f_n(x)\bigr)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ is a Cauchy sequence of elements of $Y$ and therefore it converges. Define$$f(x)=\lim_{n\to\infty}f_n(x).$$

Now, I will prove that $(f_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ converges to $f$. Take $\varepsilon>0$ and take $\varepsilon'\in(0,\varepsilon)$. There is some natural $p$ such that$$m,n\geqslant p\implies d(f_m,f_n)<\varepsilon'.$$So, if you fix $n\in\mathbb N$, then, for each $x\in X$,$$d_Y\bigl(f(x),f_n(x)\bigr)=\lim_{m\to\infty}d_Y\bigl(f(x),f_n(x)\bigr)\leqslant\varepsilon'.$$Therefore, $d(f,f_n)\leqslant\varepsilon'<\varepsilon$. What this means is, of course, that $\lim_{n\to\infty}f_n=f$.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! I have 2 questions:

1. Why is $d_Y(f_m(x),f_n(x))\leq d(f_m,f_n)$?

2. If (1.) is true, then why is $\lim_{n\to\infty}d_Y(f(x),f_n(x))\leq\varepsilon'$? Why not $<$?

Comment: 1. Because $d(f_m,f_n)=\sup_{z\in X}d_Y(f_m(z),f_n(z))\geqslant d_Y(f_m(x),f_n(x))$. 2. If every term of a convergent sequence is less than $\varepsilon'$, then the limit is smaller than or equal to $\varepsilon'$.

Comment: Ah, I see. So that's why you need two epsilons. Thanks!

Comment: Right! Of course, I could have just defined $\varepsilon'$ as $\frac\varepsilon2$.

Comment: One more question just came to mind: Where is the condition used that $(X,d_X)$ is compact?

Comment: It's so that the definition of $d$ makes sense.